# How can I link two classes, select and still get a list output using Entity Framework and LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two objects: PhraseCategory and Phrase.  Here's the classes:

```
public class PhraseCategory
{
    public System.Guid PhraseCategoryId { get; set; } // PhraseCategoryId
    public int PhraseCategoryShortId { get; set; } // PhraseCategoryShortId (Primary key)
    public int PhraseCategoryGroupId { get; set; } // PhraseCategoryGroupId
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 20)
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Phrase> Phrases { get; set; } // Phrase.FK_PhrasePhraseCategory
}

public class Phrase : AuditableTable
{
    public System.Guid PhraseId { get; set; } // PhraseId (Primary key)
    public string English { get; set; } // English
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; } // CategoryId

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual PhraseCategory PhraseCategory { get; set; } // FK_PhrasePhraseCategory
}
```

Can someone tell me how I could join these so that I am able to select all the phrases with for example a PhraseCategoryGroupId of 25.

Here's what I have right now but it does not take into account my need to also be able to select the Phrases with a PhraseCategory that has a PhraseCategoryGroupId:

```
        List<Phrase> phrases;

        var query = db.Phrases.AsQueryable();

        if (options.CreatedBy != 0) query = query
            .Where(w => w.CreatedBy == options.CreatedBy);

        phrases = await query
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(phrases);
```

Note that I would like to get just a flat output (hope that makes sense). What I mean is a list that contains just:

PhraseId, English and CategoryId

Comment: have you tried with something like var query = db.Phrases.AsQueryable().Include(xx=>xx. PhraseCategory).Where(yy=>yy. PhraseCategoryGroupId == 25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

```
phrases = phrases.Where( x => x.PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryGroupId == 25 )
                 .Select( x => new 
                         { 
                            PhraseId = x.PhraseId, 
                            English = x.English, 
                            CategoryId = x.CategoryId 
                         });
```

Please note that you can also create instances of another type instead of the anonymous type which I am creating in the above query.

Also, the `PhraseCategory` will be lazy loaded in the above query since you have lazy loading enabled on the property: it is virtual. If you have lazy loading disabled globally, then you will need to use the `Include` method in your query. Then your query will become:

```
phrases = phrases.Include(x => x.PhraseCategory)
                 .Where( x => x.PhraseCategory.PhraseCategoryGroupId == 25 )
                 .Select( x => new 
                               { 
                                  PhraseId = x.PhraseId, 
                                  English = x.English, 
                                  CategoryId = x.CategoryId 
                                });
```

Comment: To make a very complete answer. Can you also show the code for if lazy loading is disabled.  Thanks